# Can argparse parse arguments conditionally?

Tags: python, argparse

I use `argparse` in Python 2.7 to parse the command line arguments. Is there some predefined conditional parsing that would handle the following examples?

- If `-x1` is specified, then `-x2 -x3` must be specified, but`-x4` is optional.
- If `-x5` is specified then `-x4` must be specified, but `-x2` is optional.

Is there a way to do this without writing conditions after `parser.parse_args()`?

Comment: "without writing conditions after parser.parse_args()": why is that important to you? I find it rather common to first call this method and, afterwards, implement additional logic which is not simple to cover with argparse-builtin methods.

Comment: no i meant with "without writing conditions after parser.parse_args()" that i could write with someting like an possible condition-statement something like this `parser.add_argument('-x1, '--xx1, condition=(x2,x3,-x4))`. Now clear what i mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Python bug issue asking for 'necessarily inclusive' groups to `argparse`, modeled on the `mutually exclusive groups` approach.  http://bugs.python.org/issue11588

The main idea proposed there is to apply combination rules like yours right before exiting `parse_args`.  At this point there is a list (or set) of arguments that have been seen.  The main challenge to design a user interface that is comprehensive, logical, and intuitive.  It is also challenging to write usage line that reflects the conditions.

But without that patch, I'm afraid you are stuck with writing your own tests based on the values that you find in args Namespace.  If you pick your defaults correctly this shouldn't be hard.

Another possibility is to use subparsers.  You'd have to change `-x1`, `-x5` to positional choices, `x1` and `x5`, and of course they would be mutually exclusive.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27258765/901925
A simple test example:

```
if args.option1 is None and args.option2 is None:
    parser.error('at least one of option1 and option2 is required')
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i meant. I'll have an eye on that and in the meantime i use a hugh load of if-statements ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can write the condition *before* the final `parser.parse_args(...)` and re-parse:

```
 # ... args = parser.parse_args(arguments)

 try:
     if args.x1:
         # add more conditions
         parser.add_argument("-x2", ... )
 except NameError:
     # x1 not specified
     pass

 # add the rest

 # re-parse arguments
 # ... args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example

Invoke it like:

> ```
> ./foo.py --first opt2 --second bar3 # bad
> ./foo.py --first opt2 --second bar1 # ok
> ./foo.py --first opt1 --second foo1 # ok
> ```

hth

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import argparse

    FIRST_CHOICES        = [ 'opt1', 'opt2' ]
    FIRST_CHOICE_DEFAULT = 'opt1'

    SECOND_CHOICES        = [ 'foo1', 'foo2' ]
    SECOND_CHOICE_DEFAULT = 'foo1'

    SECOND_ALTERNATIVE_CHOICES        = [ 'bar1', 'bar2' ]
    SECOND_ALTERNATIVE_CHOICE_DEFAULT = 'bar1'


    class ArgsActionFirstChoicesStrings():
        def __init__(self):
            self.choices = FIRST_CHOICES
        def tostring(self):
            return ', '.join([repr(action) for action in self.choices])


    class ArgsActionFirst(argparse.Action):
        def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
            if nargs is not None:
                raise ValueError("nargs not allowed")
            self.args = ArgsActionFirstChoicesStrings()
            super(ArgsActionFirst, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
            if value:
                if value not in self.args.choices:
                    message = ("invalid choice: {0!r} (choose from {1})"
                               .format(value, self.args.tostring()))

                    raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, message)
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, value)
            else:
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, FIRST_CHOICE_DEFAULT)


    class ArgsActionSecondChoicesStrings():
        def __init__(self):
            self.choices = SECOND_CHOICES
        def tostring(self):
            return ', '.join([repr(action) for action in self.choices])


    class ArgsActionSecond(argparse.Action):
        def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
            if nargs is not None:
                raise ValueError("nargs not allowed")
            self.args = ArgsActionSecondChoicesStrings()
            super(ArgsActionSecond, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
            if value:
                if value not in self.args.choices:
                    message = ("invalid choice: {0!r} (choose from {1})"
                               .format(value, self.args.tostring()))

                    raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, message)
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, value)
            else:
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, FIRST_CHOICE_DEFAULT)

    class ArgsActionSecondAlternativeChoicesStrings():
        def __init__(self):
            self.choices = SECOND_ALTERNATIVE_CHOICES
        def tostring(self):
            return ', '.join([repr(action) for action in self.choices])


    class ArgsActionSecondAlternative(argparse.Action):
        def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
            if nargs is not None:
                raise ValueError("nargs not allowed")
            self.args = ArgsActionSecondAlternativeChoicesStrings()
            super(ArgsActionSecondAlternative, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
            if value:
                if value not in self.args.choices:
                    message = ("invalid choice: {0!r} (choose from {1})"
                               .format(value, self.args.tostring()))

                    raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, message)
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, value)
            else:
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, SECOND_ALTERNATIVE_CHOICE_DEFAULT)


    def test_common_parse_arguments():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("test")

        parser.add_argument('--first',
                            action=ArgsActionFirst,
                            default = FIRST_CHOICE_DEFAULT,
                            metavar='ACTION',
                            help="Operating system, choose from: " +
                                 ArgsActionFirstChoicesStrings().tostring())

        args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

        try:
            if args.first == "opt1":
                parser.add_argument('--second',
                                    action=ArgsActionSecond,
                                    default = SECOND_CHOICE_DEFAULT,
                                    metavar='ACTION',
                                    help="SECOND choose from: " +
                                        ArgsActionSecondChoicesStrings().tostring())
                parser.parse_args()

            elif args.first == "opt2":
                parser.add_argument('--second',
                                    action=ArgsActionSecondAlternative,
                                    default = SECOND_ALTERNATIVE_CHOICE_DEFAULT,
                                    metavar='ACTION',
                                    help="SECOND choose from: " +
                                        ArgsActionSecondAlternativeChoicesStrings().tostring())
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown os, choices are: " +
                                 ArgsActionFirstChoicesStrings().tostring())
        except NameError:
            pass

        args = parser.parse_args()

        print("first option is {}".format(args.first))
        print("second option is {}".format(args.second))

        return args


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        test_common_parse_arguments()
```